# Unable to push code in git remote from Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

i'm tring to push code in git remote from Intellij.
The stacktrace is:

```
13:17:57.195: [..\..\uiautomation] git -c core.quotepath=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/v16.2rc_Local:v16.2rc --force --follow-tags
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 993 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://raj@localhost:29418/platform/test/uiautomation
!   refs/heads/v16.2rc_Local:refs/heads/v16.2rc [remote rejected] (prohibited by Gerrit)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (6/6)        
remote: Branch refs/heads/v16.2rc:        
remote: You are not allowed to perform this operation.        
remote: To push into this reference you need 'Push' rights.        
remote: User: raj        
remote: Please read the documentation and contact an administrator        
remote: if you feel the configuration is incorrect        
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done            
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://raj@localhost:29418/platform/test/uiautomation'
```

It is working fine when I'm pushing from cmd

Comment: It is working fine when I'm pushing from cmd

Comment: format your question

Comment: Did you resolve the code review? You're running Gerrit it seems ... https://www.gerritcodereview.com/

Comment: Yes, code is resolved. Actually I'm getting this error while pushing from Intellij but when I'm pushing code from commandline it show no error.

Answer (score 1):

How to generate ssh key in GitHub

1. Open cmd from Administrator.
2. Type  ssh-keygen than press Enter
3. Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\asus/.ssh/id_rsa):  Press Enter key or (Type here filepath where you want to save the file).
4. Enter passphrase : No need to type anythings simply Press Enter Key
5. Enter same passphrase again:  No need to type anythings simply Press Enter Key
6. Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\asus/.ssh/id_rsa.
7. Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\asus/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
8. The key fingerprint is:
9. The key's randomart image is:
10. +---[RSA 2048]----+
11. |      .=...      |
12. |    . o *o .     |
13. |     + =  o .    |
14. |      + o= .  .  |
15. |   . o.oS .  . ..|
16. |    +. =o.+   ..E|
17. |     +=oo* ... o.|
18. |    . =++ o. .o. |
19. |       +oo .o..oo|
20. +----[SHA256]-----+
21. 
22. C:\Windows\system32>
23. After This close cmd and go here C:\Users\asus/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. open the file and copy the text.
24. Before OpenSSH was included with Windows, the PuTTY tool was the gold standard for generating SSH keys.
    Step 1: Install PuTTY
25. Browse to the developer’s page, and download the installer for PuTTY:
    •
    •
    •   [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)
26. Double-click the downloaded file and follow the installation wizard to finish the installation.
    •
    •
    •   On the initial dialog of the installation wizard, click Next.
    •   Select the destination folder. Use the default installation configuration unless you have a specific need to change it. Click Next to move on to the next screen.

•
•
•   Select PuTTY product features to be installed. Stick to the defaults if you do not have any specific needs. Click Next to move on to the next screen.

•
•
•   Once the process completes, click Finish to exit the installation wizard.
Step 2: Run the PuTTY SSH Key Generator

1. Press the Windows key.
2. Type puttygen.
3. Under Best Match, right-click PuTTYgen.
4. Click Run as administrator.
5. If prompted, click Yes on the Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device? pop-up.
   Step 3: Use PuTTY to Create a Pair of SSH Keys
   The process outlined below will generate RSA keys, a classic and widely-used type of encryption algorithm. The PuTTY keygen tool offers several other algorithms – DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519, and SSH-1 (RSA).
   If you require a different encryption algorithm, select the desired option under the Parameters heading before generating the key pair.
6. In the PuTTY Key Generator window, click Generate.
7. Move the cursor around in the gray box to fill up the green bar.
8. Save the public key:
   •
   •
   •   Click the button labeled Save public key.
   •   Choose a location to save the key.
   •   Give the key a name (e.g., putty_key.pub)
   •
   •
9. Save the private key:

Click the Conversions menu at the top.
Click Export OpenSSH key.
You’ll be asked if you want to save a key without a passphrase. Click Yes.
Choose a location to save the key (usually the same folder as the public key).
Give the key a name (e.g., putty_key).
Using Your SSH Keys Copy the ssh key and Go to GitHub.
Open the Setting of the github account and Go to SSH AND GPG Key
Press add key button and Paste the  key in Description Box. And Name the Title.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoD2F.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn how to use the formatting features of the answer editor. What part of this set of instructions addresses the question that was asked?

Answer (score 0):

First try to [Cleaning out the system caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/cleaning-system-cache.html).

Then, if the error is still there, check and delete the `.git` folders in your project subfolders. There sould be only one `.git` folder in the root of the project.

Comment: I performed the cleanup task and also check .git fil, but still I'm getting the same error.